# jquery close X on a container-fluid

Tags: jquery, containers

I have the following:

```
 <div id="AreaContainer" class="container-fluid scrollBox fluidCentrePosition" style="display:none" title="Area">
                            <div>
```

[image]

The close X in the top right hand side is what I am interested in. When it is clicked it closes the container as expected. My question is how do I get 'notified' that this has occurred? I cannot get the below .close to work, where in the above 'div' line can I link to the close X?

```
   $('.close').click(function () {
                $('#AreaContainer').parent().hide();
                alert(".close working!");
            })
```

if i try to add this:

```
<button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
```

I get a second X in the top right which I don't want, but the ('.close').click(function () works!?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In html you gave id="areaContainer" and in jquery you are using it as "#AreaContainer"
capital case.

Comment: sorry typo in post, updated now

Comment: the $('.close').click(function ()  line seems to be activated whenever I select a radio button, when it should only work when the X is selected...